# IBM WebSphere 8 memory leaks with Axis2 Web Services

Tags: memory-leaks, websphere, apache-axis

Migrated an application to WebSphere v8 from v6 and started getting memory leaks. The primary suspect is org.apache.axis2. It looks like each time the application calls a web service, an object called ServiceClient is created by WAS8 and stored in something that's called ClientConfigurationContextStore and then never garbage collected. Has anybody had a similar issue?

Comment: Presumably you're using Axis as an external library? Have you considered using WAS' built-in Web Service support, like JAX-WS? Its implementation is built on Axis, but presumably would be more predictable (and supported).

Comment: Yes, the application uses Axis. But it's a monstrous legacy application written/tweaked/patched over the past 10 years with tons of business logic all over the code. So I'd rather not change the code but tweak the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem by forcing original axis 1.4 over supplied soap implementation. This was done by placing two files in WEB-INF/services of the application. First file is called javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory and contains 'org.apache.axis.soap.MessageFactoryImpl' and the second is called javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory and contains 'org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl'. So now in the code this: javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance() returns a org.apache.axis stuff while before it was returning com.ibm.ws.webservices stuff. No memory leaks anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the problem in WebSphere v6, it's possible it is a leak in v8 itself. But it's also possible that v8 is being more strict about something that v6 was letting you get away with.

Have you checked that you're reusing all the Axis2 client objects that you can, rather than recreating ones on every call that you don't need to recreate? I recall us having some leakage in Axis2 client code under WAS v6.1 and realizing that we were recreating objects that we could be reusing instead.

Answer (score 0):

In one of our projects, we used Axis2 1.6.2 as service client. Application server was WebSphere 7 and in test environment it got out of memory from time to time. When i examined heap dump AxisConfiguration class had lots of AxisService class instances. I was instantiating  ServiceClient for every request and i saw that sometimes garbage collection worked late to finalize this object. So we used ServiceClient singleton and that solved our problem.