# Java memory leak while using Axis2 and WAS 7

Tags: java, websphere, out-of-memory, apache-axis

I have a standalone application that is running in IBM Websphere 7.0.0.19. It is running in Java 6 and we pack an Axis2 JAR in our EAR. We have 'parent last' style class loading and we have disabled the Axis service that is packed with WAS7 by default.

Recently, after 6+ weeks of continuous functioning, the application experienced an OOM. Perplexing point is, the application is deployed seperately on 2 different machines. But only one machine went down. Second machine is still up.

We checked OS, server configuration like classloader policy using WAS console and they are similar in both machines.

When the application crashed, it generated a .phd file which we analysed using Eclipse Memory Analyser Tool (MAT). The analysis is shown in the screenshot.

[image: Eclipse Memory Analysis Tool Output]

If I'm correct the bootstrap class loader is repeatedly loading and holding on to references of AxisConfiguraiton and so GC is unable to collect them when it runs. But, if that is the case, then both servers must have come down. But only one server experienced an OOM. Memory allocated to JVM is same in both machines.

We are not sure whether the issue is with WAS 7 or with axis2-kernel-1.4.1.jar or with something else.

http://www.slideshare.net/leefs/axis2-client-memory-leak
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3870
http://java.dzone.com/articles/12-year-old-bug-jdk-still-out

(Links may not refer to the current issue. But they are just pointers)

Has anyone experienced something similar ?

Comment: Can you try it on 7.0.0.25 (to exclude its a bug in websphere)

Comment: @AviramSegal - Is there a known bug in WAS 7.0.0.19 that may cause this issue ? Even if I change that, don't you think it will take huge amount of time to replicate this issue. 

Also, if it is a bug with Websphere, why didn't the second server go down ? Only one server experienced OOM, other one is still up.

Comment: Nothing concrete I know about but you can never know. Also, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779287/ibm-websphere-8-memory-leaks-with-axis2-web-services) might be relevant

Comment: @AviramSegal - We are already ignoring Axis that is build into WAS by IBM. We pack separate Axis2 Jar. That is the reason we org.apache.axis2..... exception in the screenshot.

Comment: My feeling is that the leak is in Axis itself and not WebSphere but I can't put my finger on exactly why. Still, I would definitely try 7.0.0.25 before anything else. Don't have much more to say, hopefully somebody who experienced it will have an answer. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

We saw memory growth and sockets left open on WebSphere 6.1 with Axis 2 1.4 in the past. It's been a long time, but my notes suggest it might be worth considering an upgrade to at least Axis 2 1.5.1 to fix [this bug with the open sockets](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-2883) and also to ensure you're not creating new objects repeatedly where a singleton exists (e.g. the Service object).

Comment: So, this is an issue with Axis 2 and not with WebSphere 7 ?

Comment: Possibly. In our case it was both with Axis and with the way our application was using it.

Comment: Oh, and I can say that we eventually quit using a custom deploy of Axis and instead used what was provided by the WebSphere Feature Pack for Web Services.